# Developing an editor from scratch + JavaScript + ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, editor

I want to develop an editor,similar to HTML editor, in Ajax, JavaScript from scratch. 
I have done a lot of research but could not find any tutorial for the same.

1. Could you please guide me on how to start - any tutorials.
2. Which tool to use to develop - netbeans or eclipse, etc.

Comment: An editor is probably one of the more difficult things to write.  How much experience do you have writing in JavaScript?

Comment: You mean a WYSIWYG editor? Good luck with that.

Comment: There are not tutorials for things as complex as an HTML editor. This is a suitably advanced topic to tackle that no tutorial would tackle it.

Comment: Which IDE? I use [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), I recommend it.

Comment: One question: why?  Isn't TinyMCE enough?

Comment: Want to develop editor to improve my exp in javascript ajax...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a WYSIWYG editor, the best thing I can point you to is the [Closure Library](http://code.google.com/closure/) editor which Google uses for both the Gmail editor and the Google Docs editor.

You can find the rationale and reasoning behind it in Chapter 9 of [Closure: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381871) by Michael Bolin. I couldn't find any free resources, but you can try just reading the code which is pretty well documented (but only if you are familiar with Javadoc, otherwise get the book). Once you learn how their editor works, I think it'll much easier for you to write your own from scratch.

Comment: Yes, I meant WYSIWYG editor using ajax and javascript. Going through Closure library. Thanks